# Find string enclosed within special characters using regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have a text file which contains the data from which I am trying to extract the part of data which is enclosed within $$. I am trying to figure out what should be the regex expression to find such strings in the file.

For example, the document have the following data.

```
This is the stackoverflow website. $$ I am looking for some web developers $$, $$ Fox jumps over the white dog $$.
```

For the above example the output should be.

1. I am looking for some web developers
2. Fox jumps over the white dog

Comment: It is all on one line? Can one of those data chunks span lines?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `gnu awk` with custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS=' *\\$\\$ *' '!(NR % 2)' <<< "$str"
```

```
I am looking for some web developers
Fox jumps over the white dog
```

- `RS=' *\\$\\$ *'` splits input into multiple records with `$$` and optional spaces on either side as record separator
- `!(NR % 2)` prints a even numbered record which is the text surrounded by `$$` on both sides.

---

Alternatively this `gnu grep` may also work:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\$\$ ).*?(?= \$\$)' <<< "$str"
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
$ grep -Po '\$\$.*?\$\$' file.txt
$$ I am looking for some web developers $$
$$ Fox jumps over the white dog $$
```

Use `-P` to use Perl regexes so we can use the `?` modifier to make `.*` non-greedy. Use `-o` to print out each matching substring on a separate line.

Answer (score -1):

If `Perl` is your option, please try:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while (/\$\$(.+?)\$\$/sg) {print $1, "\n"}' file.txt
```

It allows the strings in interest to span over lines although I'm not sure
if it is a requirement or not.